# Android Notification tap cause crashes the app due to Activity intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have `MainActivity` and `UserAcitivity`, I have passed some values to `UserActivity` through intent.
from the `UserActivity`, I call Notification then notification appeared, I made notification tap to
start the `UserActivity` by Pending Intent. When the Notification tap the App crashes because the values passed from `MainAcitvity` become null.
I can't Use SharedPreferences because the Value conflict for another `UserAcitivity`(the passed value was unique for every user)

example code is here:-
This is MainAcitvity

```
public void buttonClick(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("myname","ashiqueHira");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is SecondAcivity Oncreate method;

```
String heading= "";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    heading = intent.getStringExtra("myname");
    Toast.makeText(this, heading, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This is my Notification method

```
public void notificationPops(){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    createNotificationChannel();
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent);
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_vibration_black_24dp)
            .setContentTitle("Token Reminder")
            .setContentText("Dismiss the Alarm by Clicking this")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setVibrate(new long[] { 100, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}

private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "myChannel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        );
        serviceChannel.enableVibration(true);
        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
    }
}
```

This is a similar condition that I have. The difference is I have many usages for the getIntent value
and that value is unique for every Activity.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What if you add the user name to the `pendingIntent` before giving it to the Notification? Something like: `pendingIntent.putExtra("myname","ashiqueHira");`

Comment: I couldn't give putExtra to pendingIntent. Please tell me how to do it. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why couldn't you give `putExtra`?

Comment: I tried to put pendingIntent.putExtra below the PendingIntent Declaration shown above. but it couldn't resolve. (showing error)

Comment: What error was shown? Can you update the question with that attempt and the error message.

Comment: PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
pendingIntent.putExtra("yourName",heading); 
Cannot resolve method 'putExtra("yourName", heading)'
NotificationCompat..........and other code...........

Comment: Hello @BrunoBieri Thanks for your response I solved that problem by using this
'Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("yourName",heading);'
'PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                           0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically you get `NullPointerException`. For reducing this problem change youe `SecondActivity` code like this:

```
String heading= "";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.getStringExtra("myname")!= null){
       heading = intent.getStringExtra("myname");
       Toast.makeText(this, heading, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This will reduce your nullException error and your app cannot crash.

Another thing If you always need heading value pass through intent. Then pass the value also from notification pendingIntent and get it from `SecondActivity`

Comment: Thanks for your response, How to pass the value from PendingIntent ?

Comment: On your `NotificationPos` method add this line `intent.putExtra("myname","ashiqueHira")` after `Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);`

Comment: Thank you very much, I got you

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this problem by adding and replacing the following code
in the notificationPops() method

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("yourName",heading);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, 
intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

this will get you the value to the activity when the activity stats by notification taps.

Please post if other best practices to solve the problem above